# C# WebApi getting The parameters dictionary contains a null entry error

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, asp.net-web-api2, asp.net-web-api-routing

Have the following api method:

```
[HttpPut]
[Route("Customers/{CustomerId}/Search", Name = "CustomerSearch")]
[ResponseType(typeof(SearchResults))]
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> Search([FromBody]SearchFilters filters, long? CustomerId = null)
{
    //This func searches for some subentity inside customers
}
```

when I try `http://localhost/Customers/Search/keyword`, the following works but
when I try `http://localhost/Customers/Search`, I am getting following error:

> messageDetail=The parameters dictionary contains a null entry for
>   parameter 'CustomerId' of non-nullable type 'System.Int64' for method
>   'System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1[System.Web.Http.IHttpActionResult]
>   GetById(Int64, System.Nullable`1[System.Int64])' in '....'. An
>   optional parameter must be a reference type, a nullable type, or be
>   declared as an optional parameter.

```
[HttpGet]
[Route("Customers/Search/{keyword}", Name = "GetCustomersByKeyword")]
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> SearchCustomers(string keyword = "")
{
    //This func searches for customers based on the keyword in the customer name
}
```

Can anyone help how to fix the issue? Or correct me what am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Optional parameter should be used as the end of the template as they can be excluded from the url.

Also by using a route constraint for the customer id you will make sure that a key word is not mistaken for a customer id.

Reference: [Attribute Routing in ASP.NET Web API 2](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/web-api-routing-and-actions/attribute-routing-in-web-api-2)

```
//PUT Customers/10/Search
[HttpPut]
[Route("Customers/{CustomerId:long}/Search", Name = "CustomerSearch")]
[ResponseType(typeof(SearchResults))]
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> Search(long CustomerId, [FromBody]SearchFilters filters, ) {
    //This func searches for some subentity inside customers
}

//GET Customers/Search    
//GET Customers/Search/keyword
[HttpGet]
[Route("Customers/Search/{keyword?}", Name = "GetCustomersByKeyword")]
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> SearchCustomers(string keyword = "") {
    //This func searches for customers based on the keyword in the customer name
}
```

Comment: Thanks. In my case the CustomerId should be long? . Will it work with nullable long?

Comment: No because you cant have segments after an optional parameter.